# I have an issue in exiting react native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to exit app when a certain button click.
BackHandler.exitApp() working well on android, but not working on ios.

I think [react-native-exit-app](https://github.com/wumke/react-native-exit-app) is best solution.
But it have null object error. How to exit app in react native?
If anyone know the solving then please advance me. Thanks

[image: error screenshot]

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Actually, react-native-exit-app is the best solution. Can you share your error screen?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added my error screenshot.

Comment: Have you manually linked `react-native-exit-app` ?

Comment: @SanyamJain. Thanks for your comment. I have tried with manual link. But I have error. I added error screenshot.

Comment: @WaterFlower you have CocoaPods setup in your project?

Comment: Yes. I have cocoa pod project.

Comment: @WaterFlower if you have cocoapods in your project, then link it using pods.

Comment: Thanks. Could you advance me how to link using pods? I seems there is no specification for using pod in that library. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `react-native link react-native-exit-app` is not working well for this package.

Please try manual linking of this package.

Open this iOS project with XCode and you can reference this package from `node_modules`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After link manually I have get error. I added error screen. Could you advance me more? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for me the simple solution was going to ios directory on my react project and run pod install, run your project again and it works fine that's it.